# Тля — есть ли множественное число?

Tags: грамотная-речь, единственное-множественное-число, существительные

Как правильно написать: *отпугнуть **тлей*** или *отпугнуть **тлю***?

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта уместны. Разница лишь в том, что в первом случае мы подразумеваем отдельных членов данного семейства, а во втором — группу насекомых как единое целое. В английском есть такая же тема, которая называется "Collective nouns".

Comment: лучше «отпугнуть тлю»...а то тлей как-то режет глаз...

Comment: Можно, конечно, но множественное число у данного слова есть.

Comment: мы же подразумеваем группу насекомых как единое целое, ведь так? значит «тлю»...

Comment: Как Вам угодно.

Comment: Если это будет, допустим, сказка про двух-трёх тлей, то иначе и не напишешь.

Answer (score 1):

И всё же  употребление слов "тлей", "тлями" режет слух. Может быть, уместнее сказать "множество тли", "столько-то особей тли"...